# How do I get my program to display the right text depending on the time?

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I'm trying to have a program that displays a sertain set of text depending on what time it is. It'll only show the last line but never any of the others, no matter what I try.

I am just wanting a simple solution. What I have done is probably very incorrect but I've tried my hardest. Here's what I have so far;

```
function I() {
setTimeout(M, 1)
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = Date()
}
function M() {
setTimeout(I, 1);
var first = "8:00:00";
if (Date() > first) {
document.getElementByTag("p").innerHTML = "Hello!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a `Date` object against a string, you need to compare it against another data object, the following snippet should work as expected.

You can learn more about the data object here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```js
function updateText() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var first = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), currentTime.getMonth(), currentTime.getDate(), 8, 0, 0);
  var targetElement = document.getElementById("time");

  if (currentTime > first) {
    targetElement.innerHTML = "Hello!";
  } else {
    targetElement.innerHTML = "Not time yet!";
  }
  setTimeout(updateText, 1000);
}

updateText();
```

```html
<p id="time"></p>
```

Comment: When the *Date* constructor is called as a function it returns a string equivalent to `new Date().toString()` so the OP is actually comparing strings. ;-) PS. You should also zero the milliseconds when creating *first*.

Comment: Just wanna say, I figured out what I did wrong. I had a <p> that had "time" as the id while I was trying to use a variable with the same name as the id. I'm so sorry for my stupidity.